# Java - GridBagLayout Presetting Columns and Rows

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, gridbaglayout

i try to setup a gui with a GridBagLayout. To adjust components individually I want to have a default row and column count. So i put in my JFrame Panels but when I launch it, it still has some kind of inset. Can anybody help me?

```
// Constraints for Layout
private GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
private final int COLUMNCOUNT = 100;
private final int ROWCOUNT = 60;
// Default Panel um GBL zu init
private JPanel jpHolder;
```

...

```
public LevelView() {
    init();
}

private void init() {
    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    initGBL();

    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

private void initGBL() {
    for (int x = 0; x < COLUMNCOUNT; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < ROWCOUNT; y++) {
            if (x == 0 || y == 0) {
                jpHolder = new JPanel();
                jpHolder.setSize(10, 10);
                jpHolder.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
                gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                gbc.gridx = x;
                gbc.gridy = y;
                add(jpHolder, gbc);
            } else {
                jpHolder = new JPanel();
                jpHolder.setSize(10, 10);
                jpHolder.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
                gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
                gbc.gridx = x;
                gbc.gridy = y;
                add(jpHolder, gbc);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what it Looks like: 
[Weird inset or whatever](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4R9U.png)

Comment: Is there anything wrong with `GridLayout`? I don't know about the "insets", but `LineBorder` will draw on all four sides and this will add 2 pixels to the width and height

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes. I want to merge some cells. Till now i found out that i need to set the weightx and weighty to 1. If it is default (0) it'll set those empty areas..